# Bluetooth not working (Atheros AR5BBU22)

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, bluetooth, acer, atheros

My laptop cannot find Bluetooth devices via Ubuntu. In Windows 7 it is working properly. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and 11.10

Output of lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:288a Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0489:e03c Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
```

Output of hciconfig:

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
   BD Address: 94:39:E5:4E:FA:3A  ACL MTU: 1022:8  SCO MTU: 183:5
   UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
   RX bytes:1559 acl:0 sco:0 events:104 errors:0
   TX bytes:926 acl:0 sco:0 commands:81 errors:0
```

Output of lsmod:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
bbswitch               13355  0 
rfcomm                 47604  12 
bnep                   18281  2 
parport_pc             32866  0 
ppdev                  17113  0 
binfmt_misc            17540  1 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32474  1 
snd_hda_codec_conexant    62128  1 
snd_hda_intel          33773  3 
snd_hda_codec         127706  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel
joydev                 17693  0 
snd_hwdep              13668  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                97188  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
uvcvideo               72627  0 
videodev               98259  1 uvcvideo
hid_logitech_dj        18593  0 
snd_rawmidi            30748  1 snd_seq_midi
usbhid                 47199  1 hid_logitech_dj
hid                    99559  2 hid_logitech_dj,usbhid
arc4                   12529  2 
v4l2_compat_ioctl32    17128  1 videodev
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
ath9k                 132390  0 
mac80211              506816  1 ath9k
ath9k_common           14053  1 ath9k
snd_seq                61896  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
ath9k_hw              411112  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
snd_timer              29990  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14540  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
i915                  468651  3 
psmouse                87603  0 
snd                    78855  16 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
ath                    24067  3 ath9k,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw
cfg80211              205544  3 ath9k,mac80211,ath
drm_kms_helper         46978  1 i915
drm                   242038  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
btusb                  18288  2 
mac_hid                13253  0 
bluetooth             180104  23 rfcomm,bnep,btusb
soundcore              15091  1 snd
acer_wmi               28418  0 
mxm_wmi                12979  0 
snd_page_alloc         18529  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
i2c_algo_bit           13423  1 i915
sparse_keymap          13890  1 acer_wmi
serio_raw              13211  0 
rts_pstor             445196  0 
mei                    41616  0 
wmi                    19256  2 acer_wmi,mxm_wmi
video                  19596  1 i915
lp                     17799  0 
parport                46562  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
atl1c                  41717  0
```

Output of uname -a:

```
Linux laptop 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Output of dmesg | grep Bluetooth:

```
[    7.642818] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[    7.642839] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    7.642841] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    7.642842] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    7.642847] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    7.700557] Bluetooth: Generic Bluetooth USB driver ver 0.6
[   15.498797] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   15.498800] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   15.524883] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   15.524888] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   15.524890] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one needs a patch to properly load the firmware:

```
--- a/drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.c 2012-04-27 19:17:35.000000000 +0200  
+++ b/drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.c 2012-04-30 01:29:47.081838667 +0200  
@@ -79,6 +79,9 @@ static struct usb_device_id ath3k_table[  
    /* Atheros AR5BBU12 with sflash firmware */  
    { USB_DEVICE(0x0489, 0xE02C) },  

+   /* Atheros AR5BBU22 with sflash firmware */  
+   { USB_DEVICE(0x0489, 0xE03C) },  
+
    { } /* Terminating entry */  
 };  

@@ -95,6 +98,9 @@ static struct usb_device_id ath3k_blist_  
    { USB_DEVICE(0x13d3, 0x3375), .driver_info = BTUSB_ATH3012 },  
    { USB_DEVICE(0x04ca, 0x3005), .driver_info = BTUSB_ATH3012 },  

+   /* Atheros AR5BBU22 with sflash firmware */  
+   { USB_DEVICE(0x0489, 0xE03C), .driver_info = BTUSB_ATH3012 },  
+
    { } /* Terminating entry */  
 };

--- a/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c 2012-04-27 19:17:35.000000000 +0200  
+++ b/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c 2012-04-30 01:31:49.302182281 +0200  
@@ -135,6 +135,9 @@ static struct usb_device_id blacklist_ta  
    /* Atheros AR5BBU12 with sflash firmware */  
    { USB_DEVICE(0x0489, 0xe02c), .driver_info = BTUSB_IGNORE },  

+   /* Atheros AR5BBU22 with sflash firmware */  
+   { USB_DEVICE(0x0489, 0xe03c), .driver_info = BTUSB_ATH3012 },  
+
    /* Broadcom BCM2035 */  
    { USB_DEVICE(0x0a5c, 0x2035), .driver_info = BTUSB_WRONG_SCO_MTU },  
    { USB_DEVICE(0x0a5c, 0x200a), .driver_info = BTUSB_WRONG_SCO_MTU },
```

Comment: and how do you do that? Just copy and paste the patch in Terminal?

Comment: While this answer might be somewhat helpful, it lacks some substantial information how to actually fix this problem. That's why I downvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

Support for *Atheros AR5BBU22* is in the Kernel since `3.6.15` but additionally the proprietary firmware has to be installed on the system for bluetooth to work. It is available in the package `linux-firmware` (on ubuntu; resp. `firmware-atheros` on debian, non-free).